# CartoDB SQL string as integer

Tags: carto, typecast

Because data is imported as string, I need to query string values as if they were integers, is there something I could use to cast values to string?

Where could I find documentation for this SQL in CartoDB? I found [this](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/sql-api.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways. Screencap below

1. Just recast it as a number using the user interface, you can find the option right under the column name.
2. Select it dynamically with SQL, but there are only few cases where this makes sense.

[image: cast]

Comment: I am using SQL API and `::int` is not working for me, this works: `select * from my_table where field = '1'` but when I try `select *,field::int as xx from my_table where xx=1` is does not work, let me paste some trace

Comment: javascript console says: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` the URL seems to be ok in web console when I inspect request parameters.

Comment: the conversion to int is probably failing on empty strings or strings. you might be better off doing the conversion in the interface first

Comment: I tried on GUI too, same problem

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure why our internal conversion isn't doing this for you, but I'll forward this along to get it fixed. In the meantime, try creating a new column with type numeric. Then do an, ```UPDATE tablename SET newcolumn = replace(regexp_replace(oldcolumn, '[^0-9.]','','g'),'', null)::integer```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`select *, field::int xx from my_table where field::int=1`

You can't use column alias in a WHERE clause. 
[see this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040631/postgresql-does-not-accept-column-alias-in-where-clause)